# Time series data pre processing - model improves?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, mase

I have a time series that includes some rare extreme values. We are talking about daily data, in total 1461 observations and 11 extreme values. I adjusted those 11 values with a multiple regression. Now I am using the `tbats()` on the original time series and the adjusted one.

```
accuracy(original)
>                   ME    RMSE      MAE MPE MAPE      MASE          ACF1
>Training set 10.23539 4202.19 2921.593 NaN  Inf 0.6777689 -0.0003493096
accuracy(adjusted)
>                   ME    RMSE      MAE MPE MAPE      MASE          ACF1
>Training set 43.35625 3803.618 2787.39 NaN  Inf 0.6827622 -0.004749092

#original AIC
>35101.43
#adjusted AIC
>34798.24
```

How can I see if the model improves due to the adjustment or not? Since I reduced those 11 extreme values, I can't just compare MAE, RMSE or AIC. MASE is the only measure that should work?

I could divide MAE, RMSE and AIC by the mean of the respective time series.

```
# original
0.4962245 # MAE/mean(original)
0.7137304 # RMSE/mean(original)
5.96188 # AIC/mean(original)

# adjusted
0.4862567 # MAE/mean(adjusted)
0.6635364 # RMSE/mean(adjusted)
6.07051 # AIC/mean(adjusted)
```

Is that a legitimate way to compare the results?

Here are the `pacf`-diagrams of both models:

**original**:

[image: original]

**adjusted**:

[image: adjusted]

**Update:**

I just realized that when i use the `accuracy()` function of the `forecast` package with a `tbats()` based on a `msts()` object the resulting MASE is using an in-sample naive forecast for scaling. I guess that is not optimal? It should be better to use an in-sample naive seasonal forecast with the longest season of the `msts()` object.

```
MASE(original) # scaled with a in-sample naive seasonal forecast (365)
> 0.6339

MASE(adjusted) # scaled with a in-sample naive seasonal forecast (365)
> 0.6287
```

Comment: Any thoughts anyone?